# Language recognizer (from a sound tell whether French/Romanian/Korean/etc)

Tags: gratis, android, audio, language, speech-recognition

I want an Android app that can listen to someone speaking and tell what language it is.

Example:

1. Sound "*The Maharashtra government has given a 90-day period for manufacturers to dispose of existing polyethylene terephthalate (PET/PETE) plastic spoons and plates, while shopkeepers and citizens in general have six months to dispose of plastics.*"
2. App displays "English"
3. Sound "*Komunistička partija, marksistička-lenjinistička i maoista, prva i treća najveća partija u Predstavničkom domu Nepala, odnosno već su bili koalicioni partneri.*"
4. App displays "Bosnian"

## Requirements

- Runs on Android
- Gratis
- Ideally can listen from the Android audio output from the other apps, typically radio apps (optional)

## Context

I listen to random Internet radios, often from regions that have several languages in common use, and I often wonder what language they are speaking, with no easy way to tell from the station's metadata, additionally a single radio station sometimes has broadcasts in various languages.